# Add every nth value in row of a dataframe

Tags: r

This should be easy but I am stumped. I know I could do this in a loop but it should be easier.

I would like to add row-wise the values in every 3rd column in a dataframe. So, if I have a dataframe with 10 columns, I want to add the 1st and 4th, the 2nd and 5th, the 3rd and 6th etc. until I get to the 7th column (adding to the 10th). This is done for each row.

I can't get the various aggregating functions (e.g. rowsum, apply) to do this properly.

Example data frame below

```
x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
y = c(2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20)
z = c(3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30)
all = as.data.frame(rbind(x,y,z))
```

Thus, the result for x should be 5,7,9,11,13,15,17. The result for y is 10,14,18,22,26,30,34 etc.

Comment: `all[,1:7] + all[,4:10]` ??

Comment: Gulp! Yes, that works...

Comment: you are scaring me good sir

Comment: It is terrifying for me!

Comment: Kinda liberating isn't it?

Comment: Very nice......  I think Arun should post his suggestion as an answer.